# Any command to install all missing files for maven project in .M2 folder?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

My maven project environment was set up few months back in working condition and then I deleted my m2 folder to create a different set up of environment other project. Now, I am trying to access the maven project environment but so many dependency files missing errors are thrown.

Any idea about the command which actually installs or gets the missing files from whole system ?

or any other way ?

Comment: `mvn install` should download all the missing dependencies for your project if you have a properly defined pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted the maven repo, than you have to uninstall/install it back.
Or you have deleted the jars in User/m2/repository/com... than just simply build the project.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, we see either

1. You have deleted the Maven Source Files
2. You have deleted the Project dependency files

In first case, delete / uninstall the Maven from your system, and install a fresh package.

In the Second case, nothing to worry, just clean install for the project. Also, you could point the local repository to

```
<localRepository>c:\Maven\repository</localRepository>
```

in your POM